# pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system

Tags: python, linux, selenium

Не получается забрать данные с буфера обмена в OC linux при парсинге Selenium
Браузер Chrome
Использую приведенный ниже код

```
import pyperclip as clipboard

 
        action.perform()
        action.key_down(Keys.CONTROL)
        action.send_keys('c')
        action.key_up(Keys.CONTROL)
        action.perform()

        data = clipboard.paste()
        print(data)
```

Аналогичный код работает на Windows
в Linux Возвращает None

Установил данные утилиты

```
sudo apt-get install xsel
sudo apt-get install xclip
```

Ничего из этого не помогает

Версии:

```
Python==3.10
Ubuntu==22.04
Selenium==4.10.0
Chrome==115.0.57.90
```